# How do I switch to first person?

Tags: mad-max

I've seen many trailers and other gameplay videos showcasing how you can switch from 3rd to 1st person on the fly. However, I don't recall this ever being mentioned in the tutorials (unless I missed it) and I also don't remember seeing it in the control layout in options.
Now, I've tried pressing every button that makes sense (ie obviously leaving out the share button) but they all seem tied to an existing function/skill. Am I missing something?

I'm playing on the PS4 (left the tag out since this question isn't specifically about the PS4 itself).

Comment: Dev's also said that its for combat too

Comment: I remember reading about that a while ago. But it looks like that never made it into the game. And seeing how combat plays, I wouldn't say that's a bad thing since hand to hand would almost be impossible at times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only switch to first-person when you are driving vehicles.  To do this, quickly tap down on the d-pad twice. On the PC this is bound to the <kbd>V</kbd> key.

It is in the menu for the button mappings, but you have to change over to the button mappings for driving versus on-foot.

Comment: Ah, I bet I was looking at the on foot controls... That would make sense. I'll give it a shot when I get home, then you'll have a green check mark headed your way.